# How to make a scrollable entry list

Tags: c#, database, forms, list

Currently I am making a system in C# forms wherein I want a user to be able to look through a list of entries (each entry would show a small profile picture and name).

How do I make a scrollable list on this form where each entry can be clicked and a profile picture and a name can be grouped together?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I've tried using some groupboxes in combination with a listbox, with little to no success.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a ListView or possibly a DataGridView. Or a UserControl which you add to a FlowLayoutPanel. Without knowing more I would use an owner-drawn ListView, but maybe you find the UserControls+FLP setup easier to design.. Groupbox is just a (rather dumb) container and Listbox is simply very dumb. Whenever you use it you will find that with a ListView you will be better off ..

Comment: also if you can, use wpf, the flexibility of the framework is unlimited :)